# Angular - How to share a service provided in component with the component's resolver?

Tags: angular, angular-resolver

I have a messenger component, with a messages service provided in the component itself (as it needs to be component specific) as such:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-messenger",
  templateUrl: "./messenger.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./messenger.page.scss"],
  providers: [MessagesService],
})
```

I need to load my messages (done in the messages service) before I transition to the messenger component, and am therefore using a resolver (`messagesResolver`). The `messagesService` contains the messages, so the resolver needs access to a same instance of the `messagesService` as the `messengerComponent`.

How do I do that?

I am currently getting the error from the resolver:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(MainPageModule)[MessagesResolver -> MessagesResolver -> MessagesService -> MessagesService -> MessagesService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for MessagesService!
```

I understood from other Stack Overflow questions that I could Angular's Injector? However I don't know how I would go about this.

Notes on resolver:

- It is provided in root using `@Injectable({ providedIn: "root", })`
- It is used in the routing of the module containing the messenger component as such:

```
{
    path: "messenger/:chatID",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./chats/messenger/messenger.module").then((m) => m.MessengerPageModule),
    resolve: {
      messages: MessagesResolver,
    },
  },
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example on https://stackblitz.com/ I am not 100% sure I follow, but could using a factory provider be a better option? `{provide: MessagesService, useFactory: (messageResolver) =>{/*do stuff*/}, deps: [MessageResolver]}}`

Comment: Wow that's exactly what I needed, what you suggested worked perfectly. If you post an answer I can mark it right. I simply changed `private msgService: MessagesService` to `public msgService: MessagesService` in the `messagesResolver`, and then in `messengerComponent` provided messagesService with `useFactory: (messageResolver) => messageResolver.msgService`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a **factory** will allow you to access `services`, `components`, `properties`, `functions`, etc. when a specific service is created. This allows you to modify the creation process a little bit once the service is created such as assigning a value to a property.

```js
@Component({
  providers: [{
    provide: MessagesService, 
    useFactory: (messageResolver: MessageResolver) => messageResolver.msgService, 
    deps: [MessageResolver]
  }]
})
export class MessengerComponent {

}
```

Comment: Actually I just found this hasn't completely worked, the `MessagesService` has to be provided in root to not get `NullInjectorError: No provider for MessagesService` in the resolver. Is it possible to add the `MessagesService` as a provider of the resolver?